# Prove equality on list constructed with a map

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I have two lists, one constructed directly by recursion and the other constructed using a map operation. I'm trying to show they are equal, and surprisingly I got stuck.

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Fixpoint ls_zeroes n :=
  match n with
  | 0 => nil
  | S n' => 0 :: ls_zeroes n'
  end.

Fixpoint ls_ones n := map S (ls_zeroes n).
Fixpoint ls_ones' n :=
  match n with
  | 0 => nil
  | S n' => 1 :: ls_ones' n'
  end.

Goal forall n, ls_ones n = ls_ones' n.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction n.
  - reflexivity.
  - simpl. f_equal. (* ??? *)
Abort.
```

This is what the context looks like:

```
1 subgoal
n : nat
IHn : ls_ones n = ls_ones' n
______________________________________(1/1)
map S (ls_zeroes n) = ls_ones' n
```

I thought `fold ls_ones` would `map S (ls_zeroes n)` into `ls_ones n` since that's literally the definition of `ls_ones` but it does nothing. If I try to `unfold ls_ones in IHn` I get a nasty recursive expression instead of the verbatim definition of `ls_ones`.

What is the cleanest way to complete this proof?

Comment: `destruct n; simpl; try induction n; simpl; congruence.`  (just code golfing :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought `fold ls_ones` would `map S (ls_zeroes n)` into `ls_ones n` since that's literally the definition of `ls_ones`

Is it? You said `Fixpoint ls_ones`, not `Definition`. Just like any `Fixpoint`, this means that the given definition of `ls_ones` is transformed into a `fix`. There's no recursive structure in the definition given, so this is pointless, but you said to do it, so Coq does it. Issue `Print ls_ones.` to see the actual definition. The true solution is to make `ls_ones` a `Definition`.

If you don't fix that, Coq will only reduce a `Fixpoint` if the recursive argument(s) start with constructors. Then, in order to complete this proof, you need to `destruct n` to show those constructors:

```
Goal forall n, ls_ones n = ls_ones' n.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction n.
  - reflexivity.
  - simpl. f_equal. destruct n; assumption.
Qed.
```

Comment: Nice catch. I changed `Fixpoint` to `Definition` and `fold` still does nothing. `unfold ls_ones. simpl. f_equal. Fail progress fold ls_ones.`

Comment: @CarlPatenaudePoulin The `fold` is unnecessary. At that point, the type of `IHn` and the goal are already convertible. Just finish the proof with `exact IHn.`/etc. If you really want it, `fold (ls_ones n).`. As stated in the [documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.fold), `fold expr` first `red`uces `expr`, then searches for exact matches of that pattern in the goal. `fold ls_ones` therefore recognizes only the actual abstraction `fun m => map S (ls_zeroes m)`, not the reduction of its application `map S (ls_zeroes n)`.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that when you define ls_one and unfold the definition you gets :

```
(fix ls_ones (n0 : nat) : list nat := map S (ls_zeroes n0)) n = ls_ones' n
```

The problem is that ls_one isn't a fixpoint. Indeed, it's doesn't make a recursion. Once coq automatically defines the point {struct n0} (in that case the n argument), your proof gets stuck because n is never destructed in *P k -> P (k + 1)*, 'cause k is not destructed.
Using :

```
Definition ls_ones n := map S (ls_zeroes n).
```

The proof becomes trivial :

```
Goal forall n, ls_ones n = ls_ones' n.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction n.
  trivial.
  unfold ls_ones in *.
  simpl.
  rewrite IHn.
  trivial.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, due to the value being fixed in your definitions you must use induction to do the proof:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Fixpoint seq0 n :=
  match n with
  | 0 => nil
  | S n' => 0 :: seq0 n'
  end.

Fixpoint seq1 n :=
  match n with
  | 0 => nil
  | S n' => 1 :: seq1 n'
  end.

Lemma eq_F n : seq1 n = [seq n.+1 | n <- seq0 n].
Proof. by elim: n => //= n ->. Qed.
```

There is not a lot to proof tho. I'd recommend tho using the more general `nseq count elem` function instead of definition your own duplicate structures, then the proof follows pretty quickly from the general lemma about `map`:

```
Lemma eq_G n : nseq n 1 = [seq n.+1 | n <- nseq n 0].
Proof. by rewrite map_nseq. Qed.
```